# Track every application that is opened on the OS with Node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, operating-system

I'm looking for a way to track any application that is opened in the OS and when it is closed with Node.js.
The purpose is to track OS applications time usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use command line, try the ps command filtering "node" with grep:

```
ps | grep node
```

or

```
ps -aux | grep node
```

You need to play around the outputs to find a correct filter (using ps command line options and string to be filtered in grep) for your case.